# C++ ICU Add Break Rule for Khmer

Tags: c++, line-breaks, icu

I am trying to add better functionality to the ICU break iterator for Khmer (it uses a dictionary just like Thai).

I have a character that I always want the breakiterator to break after - but I can't figure out how to add a "rule" to the code to make it work.

The character I want to always break after is U+17CB

The U+17CB character is already contained in fEndWordSet = fKhmerWordSet; but the problem is, in the fEndWordSet it is only a *possible* end of a word. I need to change it to always break after the character rather than just as a possibility.

I am not very experienced, so any direction you can give would be very much appreciated!

Here's the current break iterator for Khmer (contained in dictbe.cpp - the whole source can be viewed [here](http://icu.sourcearchive.com/documentation/4.8.1.1-1/dictbe_8cpp_source.html)):

```
// How many words in a row are "good enough"?
#define KHMER_LOOKAHEAD 3

// Will not combine a non-word with a preceding dictionary word longer than this
#define KHMER_ROOT_COMBINE_THRESHOLD 3

// Will not combine a non-word that shares at least this much prefix with a
// dictionary word, with a preceding word
#define KHMER_PREFIX_COMBINE_THRESHOLD 3

// Minimum word size
#define KHMER_MIN_WORD 2

// Minimum number of characters for two words
#define KHMER_MIN_WORD_SPAN (KHMER_MIN_WORD * 2)

KhmerBreakEngine::KhmerBreakEngine(const TrieWordDictionary *adoptDictionary, UErrorCode &status)
    : DictionaryBreakEngine((1<<UBRK_WORD) | (1<<UBRK_LINE)),
      fDictionary(adoptDictionary)
{
    fKhmerWordSet.applyPattern(UNICODE_STRING_SIMPLE("[[:Khmr:]&[:LineBreak=SA:]]"), status);
    if (U_SUCCESS(status)) {
        setCharacters(fKhmerWordSet);
    }
    fMarkSet.applyPattern(UNICODE_STRING_SIMPLE("[[:Khmr:]&[:LineBreak=SA:]&[:M:]]"), status);
    fMarkSet.add(0x0020);
    fEndWordSet = fKhmerWordSet;
    fBeginWordSet.add(0x1780, 0x17B3);
    //fBeginWordSet.add(0x17A3, 0x17A4);      // deprecated vowels
    //fEndWordSet.remove(0x17A5, 0x17A9);     // Khmer independent vowels that can't end a word
    //fEndWordSet.remove(0x17B2);             // Khmer independent vowel that can't end a word
    fEndWordSet.remove(0x17D2);             // KHMER SIGN COENG that combines some following characters
    //fEndWordSet.remove(0x17B6, 0x17C5);     // Remove dependent vowels
//    fEndWordSet.remove(0x0E31);             // MAI HAN-AKAT
//    fEndWordSet.remove(0x0E40, 0x0E44);     // SARA E through SARA AI MAIMALAI
//    fBeginWordSet.add(0x0E01, 0x0E2E);      // KO KAI through HO NOKHUK
//    fBeginWordSet.add(0x0E40, 0x0E44);      // SARA E through SARA AI MAIMALAI
//    fSuffixSet.add(THAI_PAIYANNOI);
//    fSuffixSet.add(THAI_MAIYAMOK);

// Compact for caching.
fMarkSet.compact();
fEndWordSet.compact();
fBeginWordSet.compact();
//    fSuffixSet.compact();
}

KhmerBreakEngine::~KhmerBreakEngine() {
delete fDictionary;
}

int32_t
KhmerBreakEngine::divideUpDictionaryRange( UText *text,
                                            int32_t rangeStart,
                                            int32_t rangeEnd,
                                            UStack &foundBreaks ) const {
if ((rangeEnd - rangeStart) < KHMER_MIN_WORD_SPAN) {
    return 0;       // Not enough characters for two words
}

uint32_t wordsFound = 0;
int32_t wordLength;
int32_t current;
UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
PossibleWord words[KHMER_LOOKAHEAD];
UChar32 uc;

utext_setNativeIndex(text, rangeStart);

while (U_SUCCESS(status) && (current = (int32_t)utext_getNativeIndex(text)) < rangeEnd) {
    wordLength = 0;

    // Look for candidate words at the current position
    int candidates = words[wordsFound%KHMER_LOOKAHEAD].candidates(text, fDictionary, rangeEnd);

    // If we found exactly one, use that
    if (candidates == 1) {
        wordLength = words[wordsFound%KHMER_LOOKAHEAD].acceptMarked(text);
        wordsFound += 1;
    }

    // If there was more than one, see which one can take us forward the most words
    else if (candidates > 1) {
        // If we're already at the end of the range, we're done
        if ((int32_t)utext_getNativeIndex(text) >= rangeEnd) {
            goto foundBest;
        }
        do {
            int wordsMatched = 1;
            if (words[(wordsFound+1)%KHMER_LOOKAHEAD].candidates(text, fDictionary, rangeEnd) > 0) {
                if (wordsMatched < 2) {
                    // Followed by another dictionary word; mark first word as a good candidate
                    words[wordsFound%KHMER_LOOKAHEAD].markCurrent();
                    wordsMatched = 2;
                }

                // If we're already at the end of the range, we're done
                if ((int32_t)utext_getNativeIndex(text) >= rangeEnd) {
                    goto foundBest;
                }

                // See if any of the possible second words is followed by a third word
                do {
                    // If we find a third word, stop right away
                    if (words[(wordsFound+2)%KHMER_LOOKAHEAD].candidates(text, fDictionary, rangeEnd)) {
                        words[wordsFound%KHMER_LOOKAHEAD].markCurrent();
                        goto foundBest;
                    }
                }
                while (words[(wordsFound+1)%KHMER_LOOKAHEAD].backUp(text));
            }
        }
        while (words[wordsFound%KHMER_LOOKAHEAD].backUp(text));
foundBest:
        wordLength = words[wordsFound%KHMER_LOOKAHEAD].acceptMarked(text);
        wordsFound += 1;
    }

    // We come here after having either found a word or not. We look ahead to the
    // next word. If it's not a dictionary word, we will combine it with the word we
    // just found (if there is one), but only if the preceding word does not exceed
    // the threshold.
    // The text iterator should now be positioned at the end of the word we found.
    if ((int32_t)utext_getNativeIndex(text) < rangeEnd && wordLength < KHMER_ROOT_COMBINE_THRESHOLD) {
        // if it is a dictionary word, do nothing. If it isn't, then if there is
        // no preceding word, or the non-word shares less than the minimum threshold
        // of characters with a dictionary word, then scan to resynchronize
        if (words[wordsFound%KHMER_LOOKAHEAD].candidates(text, fDictionary, rangeEnd) <= 0
              && (wordLength == 0
                  || words[wordsFound%KHMER_LOOKAHEAD].longestPrefix() < KHMER_PREFIX_COMBINE_THRESHOLD)) {
            // Look for a plausible word boundary
            //TODO: This section will need a rework for UText.
            int32_t remaining = rangeEnd - (current+wordLength);
            UChar32 pc = utext_current32(text);
            int32_t chars = 0;
            for (;;) {
                utext_next32(text);
                uc = utext_current32(text);
                // TODO: Here we're counting on the fact that the SA languages are all
                // in the BMP. This should get fixed with the UText rework.
                chars += 1;
                if (--remaining <= 0) {
                    break;
                }
                if (fEndWordSet.contains(pc) && fBeginWordSet.contains(uc)) {
                    // Maybe. See if it's in the dictionary.
                    int candidates = words[(wordsFound+1)%KHMER_LOOKAHEAD].candidates(text, fDictionary, rangeEnd);
                    utext_setNativeIndex(text, current+wordLength+chars);
                    if (candidates > 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                pc = uc;
            }

            // Bump the word count if there wasn't already one
            if (wordLength <= 0) {
                wordsFound += 1;
            }

            // Update the length with the passed-over characters
            wordLength += chars;
        }
        else {
            // Back up to where we were for next iteration
            utext_setNativeIndex(text, current+wordLength);
        }
    }

    // Never stop before a combining mark.
    int32_t currPos;
    while ((currPos = (int32_t)utext_getNativeIndex(text)) < rangeEnd && fMarkSet.contains(utext_current32(text))) {
        utext_next32(text);
        wordLength += (int32_t)utext_getNativeIndex(text) - currPos;
    }

    // Did we find a word on this iteration? If so, push it on the break stack
    if (wordLength > 0) {
        foundBreaks.push((current+wordLength), status);
    }
}

// Don't return a break for the end of the dictionary range if there is one there.
if (foundBreaks.peeki() >= rangeEnd) {
    (void) foundBreaks.popi();
    wordsFound -= 1;
}

return wordsFound;
}
```

Comment: Haha, I thought "Hey! Someone else on SO was working on Khmer recently" -- [turns out it was you, and not so recent](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4861619/377270). *sigh*.

Comment: :) yeah, we've made progress - at least there is code for Khmer word breaking now.  But there still is a lot more work to be done, and most of the time I don't have a clue! But I am grateful for all the help I have received thus far.

Comment: @Nathan Hello again Nathan.  This is probably a better discussion for the ICU mailing lists - http://site.icu-project.org/contacts  - also, it would be better to link to an official ICU source archive, such as on http://icu-project.org  - finally, it would be better to base the work on current trunk rather than 4.8.

Please send a note and /.or file a ticket against ICU.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right - actually someone from Google (from trying to get a Khmer spelling checker into Chrome) has opened up a ticket for Khmer and Thai requesting new features that should help out a lot!